# How can I write a 3D vector as a combination of other 3 perpendicular vectors with random lengths

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

I have $3$ vectors $v_1$, $v_2$, $v_3$. They are all perpendicular to each other, although they have different lengths.

Given a vector $v$, is there an quick algorithm to write $v$ as a combination of $v_1$, $v_2$ and $v_3$?

In other words, if $v = av_1 + bv_2 + cv_3$, is there a quick algorithm to evaluate $a$, $b$ and $c$?

I'm developing a game and this evaluation needs to be done for every single moving entity, so I'm searching for a cheap way to perform this operation a lot of times each frame.

Comment: Use the dot product!

Comment: @TedShifrin you mean something like $a = dot(v, v_1)$, $b = dot(v, v_2)$ and $c = dot(v, v_3)$? If I remember well, the dot product returns a projection of the first vector onto the second. Is that right?

Comment: Yes, except you need to pay attention to the lengths of the $v_i$.

Comment: Hmm... I'm guessing I need to divide the result by the length of the vector? In other words, $a = \dfrac{dot(v, v_1)}{|v_1|}$?

Comment: Don't guess. Dot the equation $v=av_1+bv_2+cv_3$ with $v_1$. What do you get?

Comment: I took some vectors $v_1 = \begin{pmatrix} -1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ \end{pmatrix}$, $v_2 = \begin{pmatrix} 2 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ \end{pmatrix}$ and $v_3 = \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ -3 \\ 3 \\ \end{pmatrix}$. They are all perpendicular and have random lengths. I chose $v = \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 2 \\ 4 \\ \end{pmatrix}$. I did the linear system and found $a = \dfrac{5}{3}$, $b = \dfrac{4}{3}$ and $c = \dfrac{1}{3}$. As you suggested, I took the dot product between $v_1$ and $v$, which is $5$. I did not understand the relation between $5$,  $a$ and the magnitude of $v_1$ (which is $\sqrt{3}$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $v=av_1+bv_2+cv_3$, then
\begin{align*}
v\cdot v_1 &= (av_1+bv_2+cv_3)\cdot v_1 = a(v_1\cdot v_1) + b(v_2\cdot v_1) + c(v_3\cdot v_1) \\
&= a\|v_1\|^2 + b(0) + c(0) = a\|v_1\|^2.
\end{align*}
Thus, $a = \dfrac{v\cdot v_1}{\|v_1\|^2}$. Similarly, $b = \dfrac{v\cdot v_2}{\|v_1\|^2}$ and $c = \dfrac{v\cdot v_3}{\|v_3\|^2}$.